# Create new log4net log file on demand

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have some db-related functionality which I wont to log separately. Lets say, I start db-related process and for each process I need different log file with a name: `Processing_DB_DateTime`.

I only found how to configure log4net so it create new log file for each application run:

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="App-%date{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%2thread] %-5level - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<logger additivity="false" name="LogFileAppender">
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
</logger>
```

And I can get it with code:

```
LogManager.GetLogger(name)
```

Is there a way to tell log4net to create new file when I need it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below mentioned code

```
            Log4NetInitializer.init();
            log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy h = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)log4net.LogManager.GetRepository();
            foreach (IAppender a in h.Root.Appenders)
            {
                if (a.Name == "rollingFile")
                {
                    FileAppender fa = (FileAppender)a;

                    string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFilePath"] + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".txt";
                    fa.File = path;
                    fa.ActivateOptions();

                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about doing it manually from code. Any changes to achieve through configuration file?

Comment: Got it, what I asked was Is there a way to do this via config file and not messing with code?

Comment: you can set file size when file size reached at mentioned size in config it will create a new file

Comment: <maximumFileSize value="10000KB"/>

Comment: Nope, it's not an option. I can relay on file size or datetime file was created.

Comment: I don't think so using configuration it will be done